# HTML content displaying problem with flash content in IE8

Tags: html, flash

The HTML content below the flash content not displaying in IE8 browser. Here is the code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,24" width="100%" height="100%">
 <param name="movie" value="main.swf" />
 <param name="quality" value="high" />
 <param name="menu" value="false" />
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <!--[if !IE]> <-->
  <object data="main.swf" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="menu" value="false" />
     <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
     <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
     FAIL (the browser should render some flash content, not this).
  </object>
 <!--> <![endif]-->
</object>
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: It's difficult to say with the broken syntax. Best is to post a link to an example page. And read the help pages to learn how to post HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Please check this URL "http://interwovenmarketing.com/", In this page the bottom links are in html code, but this text not displaying in IE8 Browser.

Please help me....

Comment: removing half the html is *not* fixing the formatting.

Comment: So the problem isn't about the flash, but the text below it? That's probably the use of height="100%". NB: You should validate your page: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Finterwovenmarketing.com%2F

Comment: The site you posted looks the same in IE 8 and Firefox 3.6. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than debugging this, you can do cross-brower Flash embedding with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Comment: Sorry, but IMHO using JavaScript to "correct" bad coding just makes things worse.